# Isomorphism between 2 groups whose non-identity elements equal 2

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Prove that $U_8$ is isomorphic to the group of matrices 
>   $$G=\{\pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 &  1}, \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1},\pmatrix{-1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1},\pmatrix{-1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1}\}$$

I understand that As the order of the non-identity elements of the group $U_8$ and the group G is, for all, 2 (both groups under the operation multiplication).

Any input is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you had a look at the Cayley tables yet?

Comment: yes i have looked at Cayley tables.